# Transformation distorts the border radius of container in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: Container(
          //padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          height: 50,
          width: 320,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0))),
          child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Transform(
                  alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                  transform: Matrix4.diagonal3Values(4.0, 1.0, 1.0),
                  child: Container(
                      height: 45,
                      width: 45,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        //color: Color(0xffff8d27),
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))
                      )),
                ),
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'Reservation',
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Icon(Icons.attach_money)),
                Expanded(
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'Now',
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )
          ])))
```

[This is the current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lF73g.png)

I have used a stack with the bottom layer being a container with grey color and 15.0 border radius aligned in the center, and the top layer containing text in two expandables and an icon in centre. I am trying to implement a two way slider button. I have not implemented the sliding part yet but that won't be an issue. When the user slides on a particular side the grey colored container in the bottom of stack streches on the respective side of the slide in turn depicting a selection. I am using the transform widget to scale the container in x dimension or simply speaking stretching it. The problem is that this transformation tends to distort the border radius of the container which is not producing the desired effect.
How can I stretch or transform the container so that it does not affect the border radius?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Code result demo]

```
final _transformRight = Matrix4.identity()..translate(130.0);
final _transformLeft = Matrix4.identity(); //It means zero.
bool _shouldTransformRight = false;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  ...
    body: GestureDetector(
      child: Container(
        ...
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
        ),
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            AnimatedContainer(
              ...
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey,
                //You can create a variable to unify the 
                //borderRadius for all containers. 
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
              ),
              transform: _shouldTransformRight
                ? _transformRight 
                : _transformLeft,
            ),
            Row(...),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      onHorizontalDragEnd: (details) {
        setState(() {
          _shouldTransformRight = !_shouldTransformRight;
        });
      }
    ),
 ...
}
```

Summary of the edits that I've made to your code:

- No need to provide a shape and a corner radius for the container at the same time. Using one of them alone is sufficient.
- In the corner radius of the container I used `BorderRadius.circular(...)` instead of `BorderRadius.all(...)`, because it's shorter.
- I've replaced the first child of the `Stack` with `AnimatedContainer` and used it's transform argument to position it accordingly. The `Matrix4.diagonal3Values(4.0, 1.0, 1.0)` it was the cause for the distorted border radius.
- Lastly, I wrapped the whole widget tree in a `GestureDetector`, so that I can get the user input, which based on it I'm gonna translate the `AnimatedContainer`. You can configure which callBack of `GestureDetector` to use, here I've used `onHorizontalDragEnd`.